# Why does [selection] make you select from three distinct possibilities?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

So, [selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selection) has three disjoint sets of questions it's supposed to be put on, according to the wiki+excerpt:

1. Selecting text in e.g. textboxes.
2. Making selections with UI controls like option buttons and checkboxes.
3. Selecting survivors with genetic algorithms.

These are not semantically similar, except that two of them have to do with UI elements. So clearly something is amiss.

Unfortunately, 2k+ questions is not gonna be fun to wade through, which is probably why there's no request for it that I can see. There's also the question of which of those three (or possibly some undocumented fourth) should get to stay in [selection] and which must go into tags of their own.

Although honestly, looking at the highest-rated questions… the top (and fourth) ones are asking how to change the color of selected text (sigh), the third one is about XPath node selection, and the sixth down deals with selecting dates from a calendar control. This … doesn't look salvageable, so it'll probably all have to be burned away.

Oh yeah, the ninth one down is statistics. Because sure why not.

Comment: There are [textselection] and [html-select], but none for the genetic algorithm stage that I could find, but that could be created when there are a significant amount of those questions. This should probably be a [retag-request].

Comment: The statistics one is valid—see [Wikipedia: Selection Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). The rest should go.

Comment: Note that a similar problem exists on the [select] [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select).